# Conditional formatting/alert flag/icons in power apps tables

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am working on a Power Apps solution that should have a functionality to first check the content of an Excel file and first to check is that all necessary header columns are in the dataset. I open an excel file and send it to Power Automate to check the headers. It will compare the result set of header against a hard coded array and do intersection, so if any column missing the flow will return that header column. I could of course use Notify, but I also return 5 top rows for a preview. My hope is to use conditional formatting to a kind of table that can be used for this requirement. Perhaps a red x icon on the header or all column is red, just to alert the user for the missing field. Perhaps you can use some logic with hided fields above the table that kicks in if something suspicious is discovered.

If any of you has done this or has an idea how to solve this please let me know

regards Geir